# can i install ubuntu 14.04 instead windows 8 in acer e1 572

Tags: support

I have Acer E1 572, and  I want to install Ubuntu 14.04. instead of windows 8  will it work(Run) will  it support  A E1-572  correctly without  any interruption   :)  thanks w

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try! 
To download, first see if you have a 32 bit or 64 bit OS
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/windows-8-64-bit-32-bit.htm
Then, download the appropriate .iso
[32 bit .iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=14.04.1&architecture=i386)
[64 bit .iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=14.04.1&architecture=amd64)
After dowloading the appropriate iso, download [Linux Liveusb creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)
Plug your flashdrive in, run Lili, and follow the instructions. Change source to an iso and find the file you downloaded earlier. Now, leave the flashdrive plugged in. Restart your computer and press the key to change boot order. Can be F12, F11, F9, F8, or DEL. Find the flash drive you're using and press enter.
Your trial of ubuntu is now running! You can play around, install things, and do whatever. If you see any problems, the people here are normally more than willing to help you. When done, remove the flash drive and restart. Should go back to normal function.